# cannot load the R package 'ape'

Tags: r, package, ape

I recently had to install a new hard drive in my laptop, and so am re-installing all of my R packages. I installed R version 3.5.1 and ran the code to install all of the packages I had previously installed. However,when I come to load them, specifically the commonly used 'ape' package I get the following error:
`Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ape’: object ‘warnErrList’ is not exported by 'namespace:utils'`

I haven't been able to find a solution to this specific problem online, any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: When you say ""ran the code", we have no way of knowing _what_ code. The error message seems rather strange since `warnErrList` is exported from utils.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing it? Sometimes I have to completely remove the package from my library then run `install.packages("ape")` to make sure it's the latest version

Comment: Sorry, I get the error message when I run `library(ape)` . I tried to fix it by running `remove.packages("ape")` and then `install.packages("ape")` but I still get the error

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/tidyverse/forcats/issues/78 Maybe there is a base package like `utils` or something missing? Other users have had this issue though. When you reinstall can you add the option `dependencies = T` and see if that helps?

Comment: perfect. Not sure why that worked, only need to know it did! Not sure how to flag as answer

Comment: Made it an answer for future people now :) glad it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are likely dependencies to the `ape` package that are not installed. To resolve this reinstall the package with this command: `install.packages("ape", dependencies = T)` which will automatically install any other package that `ape` relies on.